# Using getter and Setter Method dynamically from array

Tags: php, android

I am using below method for geting value by using this type of dynamic getter method in php .Is this possible to get value in getter method java or android?

```
$objects = array("model", "make", "version");
          foreach ($objects as $object) {
              $getter = "get".ucfirst($object);
              if (is_object($iProduct->$getter())) {
                  echo "getvalue"+$iProduct->$getter()
          }
```

Comment: In Java, you can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to dynamically find out which methods exist in a class and then call them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do similar stuff with reflection:

```
String[] objects = { "model", "make", "version" };
Class k = iProduct.class;
String getter;
Method m;
for(int i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
    try {
        getter = "get" + Character.toUpperCase(objects[i].charAt(0)) + objects[i].substring(1);
        m = k.getMethod(getter, null);
        System.out.println("getvalue" + m.invoke(iProduct));
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        //this particular getter doesn't exist
    }
}
```